# Show button if it is equal to my email PHP

Tags: php, html

```
        <?php
require_once('../../config.php');

if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0){
    $qry = $conn->query("SELECT s.*,a.room_name FROM `schedule_list` s inner join assembly_hall a on a.id = s.assembly_hall_id where s.id = '{$_GET['id']}' ");
    if($qry->num_rows > 0){
        foreach($qry->fetch_assoc() as $k => $v){
            $$k=$v;
        }
    }
}
?>
<div class="container-fluid p-2">
        <p><b>Room/Hall Name:</b> <?php echo $room_name ?></p>
        <p><b>Email:</b> <?php echo strtolower($reserved_by) ?></p>
        <p><b>Date/Time Start:</b> <?php echo date("M d, Y h:i A",strtotime($datetime_start)) ?></p>
        <p><b>Date/Time End:</b> <?php echo date("M d, Y h:i A",strtotime($datetime_end)) ?></p>
        <p><b>Meeting Agenda:</b><br> <span><?php echo $schedule_remarks ?></span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <?php
            if($_SESSION['userdata']['type'] != 2 ){
        ?>
        <button type="button" id="update" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" data-id="<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>">Edit</button>
        <button type="button" id="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat" data-id="<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>">Delete</button>
        <?php
            }
        
        ?>
```

I have this code for administrator type

```
<?php
   if($_SESSION['userdata']['type'] !=2 ){
?>
```

and i have a user account

i want to show the edit and delete button if my email is equal to the email in the form

```
<p><b>Email:</b> <?php echo strtolower($reserved_by) ?></p>
```

[All the schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caUAx.png)

[Admin view data if you click on the schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LEhK.png)

[User View data if you click on the schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujsJv.png)
so i want to click the edit and delete button also if im the email creator of the schedule

This is the one i use now its working

```
 <?php
        if($_SESSION['userdata']['email'] == strtolower($reserved_by) ){
    ?>
    <button type="button" id="update" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" data-id="<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>">Edit</button>
    <button type="button" id="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat" data-id="<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>">Delete</button>
    <?php
        }   
    elseif ($_SESSION['userdata']['type'] == 1 ){
    ?>
 <button type="button" id="update" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" data-id="<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>">Edit</button>
    <button type="button" id="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat" data-id="<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>">Delete</button>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: So add a check to your if statement then, joined together with the existing one using a logical OR ...?

Comment: FYI: Only hiding those buttons, will not do the job. You need to also check whether the user has the right to edit/delete the item, when you process the submitted data. Otherwise it will be easy for anyone to mess with your data by sending manipulated requests.